# unique 6 numbers generator algorithm

Tags: visual-studio-2008, c#-4.0

I need to generate unique numbers for my C# application meeting the below requirements -.

1. 6 digit .
2. About 1000 numbers to be generated everyday

   ```
   byte[] buffer = Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray();
   return string.Concat(((int)type).ToString(), 
    BitConverter.ToInt64(buffer, 0).ToString().Substring(1,    
                   6-((int)type).ToString().Length));
   ```

currently,i am using this algorithm but duplication occurs,so i want another one fit with above requirments.

Comment: Your question is really about how to generate a set of unique random numbers. For instance, you can use an algorithm just as can be see in [generate unique random numbers](http://java.about.com/od/javautil/a/uniquerandomnum.htm).

Comment: need to generate unique numbers for my C# application meeting the below requirements -.
 1.
6 digit .

 2.
About 1000 numbers to be generated everyday


Thats my question it is so simple and clear that i am asking about algorithm to generate unique randam number

Comment: Can the numbers you generate today be duplicates of the ones you generated yesterday?

Answer (score 0):

If you're only generating 1,000 6-digit numbers, it's pretty easy:

```
int NumberToGenerate = 1000;
Random rnd = new Random();
HashSet uniqueNumbers = new HashSet<int>();
while (uniqueNumbers.Count < NumberToGenerate)
{
    int next = Random.Next(100000, 1000000);
    uniqueNumbers.Add(next);
}
```

The loop will almost certainly generate a few duplicates, but `HashSet` will reject them.

Another way to do it is to create a list of all the numbers from 100,000 to 999,999. Then, when you need a number, randomly remove an item from the list.

```
private List<int> allNumbers = new List<int>();

// in the constructor
for (var i = 100000; i < 1000000; ++i)
{
    allNumbers.Add(i);
}

private Random rnd = new Random();

public int GetNumber()
{
    var index = rnd.Next();
    var rslt = allNumbers[index];
    allNumbers.RemoveAt(index);
    return rslt;
}
```

The call to `RemoveAt` is kind of expensive. You can speed things up a bit with:

```
    // move the last number in the list to fill the hole
    allNumbers[index] = allNumbers[allNumbers.Count-1];
    // remove the last item
    allNumbers.RemoveAt(allNumbers.Count-1);
```

That will minimize the amount of memory moved in the removal.

Or, you could create the list of all numbers, shuffle them, and then return them from the front:

```
// assume you've created the list of numbers, as above
// Shuffle them
for (int i = 0; i < allNumbers.Count; ++i)
{
    int j = rnd.Next(i, allNumbers.Count);
    int temp = allNumbers[i];
    allNumbers[i] = allNumbers[j];
    allNumbers[j] = temp;
}
```

Now, you can return the top 1,000 numbers or you can write a method to return the next one in sequence whenever it's called.